# How can I grant privileges of an exisisting user to a user I created in Oracle? Thanks

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, privileges, user-permissions

The user I want the user to have the priviliges on is (HR which already exists in sql developer)
I tried :

```
create user myUser
Identified by 12345678
default tablespace ts
profile pf
Account unlock;

Grant all on HR to myUser;
```

the cmd couldn't find the HR user.
Thanks!

Comment: there is no real sql solution to this, aka clone user or create user like...however, the GUI can help you https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/12/trick-getting-all-the-privileges-grants-for-a-user/

Comment: That syntax (grant all on HR to myUser) isn't looking for user HR, it is looking for a table or procedure named HR, in the schema of the connected user issuing the command.  Please consult the official docs on commands before you start making up your own uses.  As Littlefoot said, you will need to write a script to create the actual GRANT commands you need.  And further, as he said, better to grant these to a ROLE, then grant the ROLE to the users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it wrong.

As far as I can tell, there are two types of privileges:

- system privileges (you aren't granting that)
- object privileges

There's no simple way to grant "all" (by the way, what do you call "all"?) on one user to another. You can grant e.g. `select`, `update`, `delete` ... privileges on some tables; or, you can grant `execute` privilege on a procedure or a package. But, all of that is to be done separately, one-by-one.

Yes, you can write a script which will do it for you. For example:

```
SQL> select 'grant all on ' || table_name || ' to mike;' from user_tables;

'GRANTALLON'||TABLE_NAME||'TOMIKE;'
----------------------------------------------------
grant all on EMP to mike;
grant all on DEPT to mike;
grant all on BONUS to mike;
<snip>

SQL> select 'grant execute on ' || object_name || ' to mike;'  from user_procedures;

'GRANTEXECUTEON'||OBJECT_NAME||'TOMIKE;'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
grant execute on P_TEST to mike;
grant execute on F_TEST to mike;
<snip>
```

If you spool that into a file, you'd get a script you can then execute.

Or, even better, consider creating a **role**, grant desired privileges to it, and then grant role to another user.